# How to use settrace() in a method to "Bypass" a line of code in another method?

Tags: python

I have this code that can not be touched -

```
def main():
    sandbox()

    def game_over():
        print("I sense a disturbance in the code")
        os._exit(1)
        print('The code is strong in this one')

    def win():
        # TODO fail_if_not_called_from_line_8()
        print(LOGO)
    game_over()
    win()
```

However, I can write code in the sandbox() method. The problem is, I need the output of the program to read 'The code is strong in this one' along with the LOGO in the next method. This is what I have in sandbox() right now.

```
def sandbox():
    import pdb
    frame = inspect.currentframe()
    try:

    finally:
        del frame
```

I was thinking to use inspector to get the information on the gameover() method and then using settrace somehow. Unfortunately, I am 100% new to Python and have dealt only with Java and C#. For the life of me I can not figure this out with my limited Python knowledge. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

P.S sorry if this is an easy solution

Comment: Don't mess with stack frames. Mess with `os._exit`.

Comment: Any code can be touched, you are perfectly willing to touch the Python interpreter itself by poking through the stack so why not change the code itself in the first place?